# Rspec Tests take highly variable amounts of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, garbage-collection

I started along the process of trying to speed up my tests, mostly by following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/413-fast-tests)'s suggestions. So you don't have to watch it, those are:

- Replaced "bundle exec spec" with "bin/rspec spec"
- Got rid of excess before filters
- Tagged slow tests as such for separate running
- Replaced unnecessary Factory Creates with Builds
- Used Zeus to speed up start-up time
- Applied VCR to examples that reached out to external APIs
- Deferred Garbage Collection
- (I skipped parallel testing for now, cause I want to get to the bottom of this issue, and parallel testing seems like it would just minimize/mask it)

At any rate, I can't figure out whether these changes have accomplished much, because the runtimes for my tests are highly variable. (They are variable even when I go outside of the branch I've been working on for these tests -- seems like something preexisting is causing the problem). I've run the exact same suite of tests now and gotten a wide range of runtimes, from 52 seconds to almost 1m45! Again, the EXACT same tests.

Moreover, the general trend seems to be that if I run a test a few times in a row, the runtimes go up by ~20 second intervals each time. Then if I change something small in spec_helper or wait for a while (I think the latter -- I know this has happened when I've made small changes to garbage collection), the times go back down.

My guess is that this problem is related to garbage collection -- but ideally, I'm doing that more efficiently now. I had it collect garbage every ~15 seconds,

**spec_helper.rb**

```
config.before(:all) { DeferredGarbageCollection.start }
config.after(:all) { DeferredGarbageCollection.reconsider }
```

**support/deferred_garbage_collection.rb**

```
class DeferredGarbageCollection

  DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD = (ENV['DEFER_GC'] || 15.0).to_f

  @@last_gc_run = Time.now

  def self.start
    GC.disable if DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD > 0
  end

  def self.reconsider
    if DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD > 0 && Time.now - @@last_gc_run >= DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD
      GC.enable
      GC.start
      GC.disable
      @@last_gc_run = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

and then, when that was causing the aforementioned problems, I switched to a more straightforward every-ten-test collection system:

**spec_helper.rb**

```
config.after(:each) do
  counter += 1
  if counter > 9
    GC.enable
    GC.start
    GC.disable
    counter = 0
  end
end
config.after(:suite) do
  counter = 0
end
```

I've tried to isolate this to a group of tests (models/requests/controllers), but they all seem to display some amount of variability in relation to roughly how much time they eat up.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

**EDIT** -- proof/example of what's going on here:

```
Finished in 22.88 seconds
48 examples, 0 failures
➜ my_app git:(faster-tests) ✗>zeus test spec/models
................................................

Finished in 34.89 seconds
48 examples, 0 failures
➜ my_app git:(faster-tests) ✗>zeus test spec/models
................................................

Finished in 44.68 seconds
48 examples, 0 failures
➜ my_app git:(faster-tests) ✗>zeus test spec/models
................................................

Finished in 14.36 seconds
48 examples, 0 failures
➜ my_app git:(faster-tests) ✗>zeus test spec/models
................................................

Finished in 18.74 seconds
48 examples, 0 failures
➜ my_app git:(faster-tests) ✗>
```

Note that it eventually seems to reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about all the other things you have done but I can comment on zeus. I did not alter anything in my environment except add zeus and I can run 50 examples in a couple of seconds. For tests to take as long as yours when running zeus seems wrong and I'm guessing thats your problem. After you run `zeus start` are all the zeus commands green? I also use `zeus rspec spec/....` to run my specs instead of `zeus test`.

I used this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands) and this [thoughtbot article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/40193452558/improving-rails-boot-time-with-zeus) along with the [zeus README](https://github.com/burke/zeus/blob/master/README.md). Remeber to use the appropriate Ruby version mentioned in the railscast and make sure that you dont have spork anymore if you were using spork. Also remember to install zeus outside of your `Gemfile`, zeus should not use Bundler. Anyway, my suggestion would be to focus on zeus first and get that working correctly. It has really helped for me

Comment: One side note. Assuming `zeus test` uses the default rails test task, it also runs `rake db:test:prepare` before each run, which could be the source of the slowdown. `zeus rspec spec/` doesn't do this though.